# Power down USB on standby

Tags: usb-on-the-go, 8.1-oreo, standby

I've been using USB keyboard and / RFID readers on a tablet (Android 8.1.0 on Samsung GalaxyView2). If the tablet goes standby, they keep powered, draining the tablets battery fast.

Is it possible by any means to power off attached USB OTG devices, when the tablet is on standby?

Comment: Android does not have a standby mode. I assume you are referring to the state when display is off.

Comment: @Robert yes....

Comment: A silly solution may be a usb hub with a physical switch...